# How to get info of only an entity in hibernate like lazy loading with Jersey?

Tags: java, json, hibernate, rest, jax-rs

I'm using hibernate with Jersey REST api to expose my database for an android application.

I have a problem with eager fetching that was consuming a lot of memory in android when parsing JSONs:

Let's suppose that i have the following entities: User, Answers and Questions.
Users have a lot of Answers (OneToMany), a Question have a lot of Answers (OneToMany)

A user have role like Admin and common user.

So, now, when i query an User, i'm getting all the Answers of that user, and in this answers i have the question and nested the question i have the answers of all the users and all the other users data too because is working in Eager.

I don't have to query the data of the other users, when is a common user, is a quite insecure a common user have access to all the other users data, and consumes unnecessary memory.

I thought about trying to implement the lazy loading, but, i have googled and i didn't find how do the hibernate negotiate with Jersey in this case. Because when a will try to update some entity, this entity will be probably detached and missing some information of Bidirectional relationships and this can be a problem.

How can i solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem you may annotate the relation between User and Answers with fetch type Lazy